# Graphviz: <img/> not displayed in 'svg' output image

Tags: python, svg, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am using Pygraphviz library with python 2.7. I'm generating 'svg' output images. What I like to do is to use an 'svg' image as the label of my graphs. To do that, I am using the html tag  (http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html).

Here is the part of my code that is responsible to do that:

```
dot = Digraph(comment=zone)
dot.graph_attr['label'] = "\
<\
<TABLE>\
   <TR>\
      <TD><IMG SRC=\"/path/to/svg/image\"/></TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
>"
```

The svg output image is created but my svg logo is not displayed; the table is empty)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question, but as this is the first result on google and I stumbled over this as well I thought I'd share:

- You can open the `*.svg` with a text editor to check that the links are there and point to the correct location `xlink:href="/path/to/svg/image"` (which was the case for me)
- **Make sure to open it with an application that actually loads the images** (e.g. firefox, chrome, inkscape). The default image viewer in gnome, GIMP, Krita, etc. open the image just fine, but don't load the images by default, resulting in an empty table/node.